# tkiner how change the className of my window by clicking a button

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Here's my code:

```
import tkinter as tk
Name="fds"
def change_className():
  global Name
  Name=tk.StringVar()
  Name.set("dsfsd")
window = tk.Tk(className = Name)
bool=True
button=tk.Button(window,command=change_className)
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

this's the result:
[image]

For some reason nothing happen when clicking the button.
Can someone give me a solution?
(btw i used replit.com)

Comment: Can't you just use `window.title("dsfsd")`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never updated the window title. Also I am not sure what `bool = True` should do.

This should work:

```py
import tkinter as tk
Name="fds"
window = tk.Tk(className = Name)
def change_className():
  global Name
  Name = "dsfsd"
  window.title(Name)

#bool=True
button=tk.Button(window,command=change_className)
button.pack()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perhaps, there is no need for `global` here

Comment: i just forgot to deleted "bool=True", sorry

Comment: Also I don't think it actually changes the `className` of the window. I think it only changes the title. On some OSs there is a difference between the `className` of a window and the title of that window